# post and get result in json from php file on android

Tags: php, android, eclipse, methods

I am Newbie in android. and i have searched alot and found many many codes but still i have problem.

i have a simple php like : (it has **two** variables like `q` & `number`)

```
http://domain.tld/post.php
```

and after posting data to this page, there will be a result in JSON format.

I want to get that output on the php page, and Toast that value on the android (i mean i want to have that value on a variable in eclipse)

I have checked this code :

```
public void postData() {
     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

But i can't get the output with this.

Comment: @IndraKumarS i said. i can't get json output of that page when i send data. foce close :(

Comment: Can you post your json content?

Comment: json doesn't get send, i have two strings i send to that page, and it returns a JSON, so how to get that output in android ?

Comment: How do you test ? in device or in emulator ?.... Are you get json data from php ?

Comment: On device, already activated user permition too. I get JSON from php on my pc .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the How to Ask guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chances of having an adequate answer.

Comment: Check and update whether my answer helps you

Comment: @Kala I hope it helped

Comment: @IndraKumarS yeah fix thanks dear, if you have any idea about my new problem please help again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267255/encode-a-string-to-json-in-android thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a Json parser. Please find the ServiceHandler which handles get/post requests to your server.

ServiceHandler.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.util.Log;

public class ServiceHandler {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client

            HttpParams paramsH = new BasicHttpParams();
            paramsH.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(paramsH);

            //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

In youractivity.java, Call it like this

```
String resulting_json = null;
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
String URL = "http://domain.tld/post.php";
resulting_json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, resulting_json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```